# PySpark withColumn & withField TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I can't seem to figure out how to use `withField` to update a nested dataframe column, I always seem to get `'TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable'`.

I have followed this example:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=Row(b=1, c=2))])
df.withColumn('a', df['a'].withField('b', lit(3))).select('a.b').show()
```

Which still results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\benhalicki\Source\SparkTest\spark_nested_df_test.py", line 58, in <module>
    df.withColumn('a', df['a'].withField('b', lit(3))).select('a.b').show()
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Spark Version: 3.0.3 (on Windows).

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withField` was introduced in Spark version **3.1.0**, but you're using version 3.0.3. If you look at the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html), you can see this mention about version support:

> An expression that adds/replaces a field in `StructType` by name.
>
> New in **version 3.1.0.**

For older versions, you need to recreate the struct column `a` in order to update a field:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    'a', 
    F.struct(F.lit(3).alias("b"), F.col("a.c").alias("c"))
).select('a.b').show()

#+---+
#|  b|
#+---+
#|  3|
#+---+
```

Comment: Thanks blackbishop, that was it.  Sorry had been looking at this for too long, overlooked the obvious.  Appreciate your help.  Kind regards, Ben.